# Cannot connect to server via ssh when using Mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to use [Mina](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina) to automate the deployment process for a Ruby on Rails application. I defined an user for ssh like this in my `config/deploy.rb` file:

```
set :user, 'unix-username'
```

But when I call `mina setup` the username isn't set so that the script tries to ssh to my server with the windows username of my local dev maschine (which is default behaviour, when no username is given, as I know).

What can I do to use the script successfully?

My `deploy.rb` file:

```
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'

set :application_name, 'app-name'
set :domain, 'ip-address-of-my-server'
set :user, 'unix-username'
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/app"
set :repository, 'git@github.com:path/to/repo.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :rvm_use_path, '/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh'

set :execution_mode, :exec if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/

# Optional settings:
#   set :user, 'foobar'          # Username in the server to SSH to.
#   set :port, '30000'           # SSH port number.
#   set :forward_agent, true     # SSH forward_agent.

set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

task :remote_environment do
  ruby_version = File.read('.ruby-version').strip
  raise "Couldn't determine Ruby version: Do you have a file .ruby-version in your project root?" if ruby_version.empty?

  invoke :'rvm:use', ruby_version
end

task :setup do

  in_path(fetch(:shared_path)) do

    command %[mkdir -p config]

    # Create database.yml for Postgres if it doesn't exist
    path_database_yml = "config/database.yml"
    database_yml = %[production:
  database: #{fetch(:user)}
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000]
    command %[test -e #{path_database_yml} || echo "#{database_yml}" > #{path_database_yml}]

    # Create secrets.yml if it doesn't exist
    path_secrets_yml = "config/secrets.yml"
    secrets_yml = %[production:\n  secret_key_base:\n    #{`bundle exec rake secret`.strip}]
    command %[test -e #{path_secrets_yml} || echo "#{secrets_yml}" > #{path_secrets_yml}]

    # Remove others-permission for config directory
    command %[chmod -R o-rwx config]
  end

end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      # command "sudo service #{fetch(:user)} restart"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what version of mina do you using?

Comment: 1.2.2 but also tested with 1.2.3

Comment: You can `bundle open mina` and make `p fetch(:user)` in `/lib/mina/backend/remote.rb` or use **byebug** or **pry** before [this line](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/0fe5beb699f70ac2906546cc021aa2a682997043/lib/mina/backend/remote.rb#L26) or any other technique that you like to debug the issue. Please share what will user is equal to in the **ssh** method.

Comment: Another advice is to remove code that not related to general mina configuration and run mina with a minimal config that literally do nothing. By testing that mina works correctly with your minimal config. This way you can localize the source of the problem.